# Prove that is an abelian group

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics, abelian-groups

Given the binary operation in $a \circ b \in \mathbb{R}$ defined by $a \circ b = a + b + \pi$, prove that with this operation in $\mathbb{R}$, it's an abelian group.

I know that:

Given a group $G$ and $x, y \in G $ then $ G$ is an abelian group if and only if $x\cdot y=y\cdot x$

Buw, how can be proven that $a \circ b = a+ b + \pi$ is an abelian grouop? I can not understand.

Thanks!

Comment: what would be $a\circ b$ and $b\circ a$..?? Do you mean by $R$ any set or set of real numbers...

Comment: What is $\mathfrak{R}$ ? What i s $\pi$ ?

Comment: since your defining your binary operation as something that involves addition, is addition commutative?  As @PraphullaKoushik asked, what would both $a*b$ and $b*a$ be?

Comment: $\mathfrak R$ is the set of the real numbers. and $\pi$ is PI.

Comment: then what is the problem that you are facing?

Answer (score 1):

There is a general (and easy proved) assertion: If $G(+)$ is an (abelian) group and $x\in G$ then $G(\circ)$ is an (abelian) group too, where $a\circ b=a+x+b$.